# Annotate with ggplot2 when axis is of class 'date'

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations

I'm dealing a lot with geom_line plots these days. What is the easiest way to annotate on a plot with an axis of class date? Other than to convert the date variable to a different class?

Here's my code:

```
china_trades %>% 
  filter(type %in% c("Imports")) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = month, y = dollars, group = 1)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

I would like to annotate the last data point which is at 2017-10 and 48.

Here's my plot:
[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you have tried and in which way it didn't work?

Comment: I wanted to use the `annotation` function `annotation("text", x = "2017-07", y = 48, label = "Some text")`

Comment: You say that `month` is of class `Date` (is it really?). That means you should pass a Date to `annotate` (note the correct function name) and not a character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe somebody can chime in with a pure gg way of doing this but the directlabels package has this functionality:

```
china_trades %>% 
  filter(type %in% c("Imports")) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = month, y = dollars, group = 1)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_dl(aes(label = month), method = list(dl.combine("last.points")))
```

Edit: Here's a gg way using annotate:

```
x <- as.Date(c('2016-1-1','2016-1-2','2016-1-3','2016-1-4'))
y <- c(4,1,2,3)
df <- data.frame(x,y)

lastDate<- max(x)
lastDateY <- df[x==lastDate,2]

ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  annotate(geom='text', x=lastDate,y=lastDateY, vjust=-2, label="China")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was indeed hoping for a gg way.

Comment: Added a gg way. Without your df I can't reproduce your original plot but you should be able to get there. You can use the gridExtra package to make charts where the labels run off the edge which would be useful if you're labeling the last point in line charts like this.